# Get RecyclerView from view in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have a view that 'lives' in a `RecyclerView` (inflated and added to a `ViewHolder`). Is there a way to get the `RecyclerView` that the view lives in from the view itself (without 'knowing' the `RecyclerView`)?

I tried `view.getParent()` but it returns `null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `getParent()` is returning null, it's because that ViewHolder/view have not been added to the recyclerView yet. Ergo: it doesn't have a parent.

So there're two options I can think of:

1. only call `getparent` at some later point.

For example, during `layout` the view for sure have a parent, so you could add a GlobalLayoutListener to that view `ViewTreeObserver`

```
itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addGlobalLayoutListener(new ...
```

2. use the `context`

From the context you can find the activity, and from the activity you find any view

```
Context c = itemView.getContext();
while(c instanceOf ContextWrapper && !(c instanceOf Activity)){
   c = ((ContextWrapper)c).getBaseContext();
}

if(c instanceOf Activity){
   Activity a = (Activity)c;
   RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) a.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
 }
```

ps.: all typed by heart, there might be some typos.

Comment: so u ended up implementing .1 ?

Comment: I only needed to resolve the RecyclerView of the view on a click event, when all the layouting has already happened, so no need for a onGlobalLayoutListener. When I tested my 'mechanism' I checked for the view's parents too early.

Answer (score 0):

Get the child of the Viewholder and cast it to Recyclerview.

Comment: The children of the view will not be a RecyclerView.